# Write a bootable image of system into an internal disk, without removing a data partition

Tags: partition, system-installation, grub, hard-disk, dd

I have an internal HDD like partitioned like this:

`[---- 100 GB unused ----|----------- 800 GB data ------------]`

- 100 GB of unused or "to be deleted" old partitions `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sdb3`
- 800 GB NTFS important data partition `/dev/sdb4` (I have backup)

I also have a 10GB `ubuntu.img` image of a disk containing Ubuntu installed (it is not an "installer disk" image). This image can be run from VirtualBox, or can be written to an external USB HDD with `dd if=ubuntu.img of=/dev/sdc`, and then I can successfully boot this external USB HDD. When I start this image with VirtualBox, inside the VM, `lsblk` says this:

[image]

Question: **how to write this image `ubuntu.img` into my internal HDD (on /dev/sdb? sdb1?) such that:**

- I can boot on it
- /dev/sdb4 is not erased

?

On the one hand, if I `dd if=ubuntu.img of=/dev/sdb`, the partition table will probably be erased and `/dev/sdb4` will be lost. On the other hand, if I `dd if=ubuntu.img of=/dev/sdb1`, it probably won't be bootable, is that correct?

Comment: I think you want to delete 2 of the /dev/sdb{1,2,3} partitions and make the third the same size as the internal sda1 partition in the image. For ease of doing it, I would boot the USB HDD and then use `dd` to copy the `1` partition on whatever drive the booted USV is to the `1` drive on whatever the sdb drive now is (rebooting from different media frequently changes drive names, be **very careful** to double check. At this point you probably need to install grub, then set the BIOS to boot the drive.

Comment: You will have an incorrect partition table if you use `dd if=ubuntu.img of=/dev/sdb` the /dev/sdb4 partition will not be accessible, but the data will be intact. Writing down the detailed parameters before you use will enable you to recreate the partition table entry.

Comment: `dd if=ubuntu.img of=/dev/sdb1` doesn't get you anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `fdisk` to `d`elete volumes `sdb1` to `sdb3`
2. Still in `fdisk`, create a `n`ew volume `sdb1`, covering the whole free 100 GB
3. Now you only want to copy `sda1` of your image to `sdb1`, so do `fdisk ubuntu.img` and `p`rint the partition table of the image and read the start sector and number of sectors of the first image partition
4. `dd if=ubuntu.img of=/dev/sdb1 skip=<start-sector> count=<sectors>`
5. Finally you can extend the file system on `sbd1` to use the whole size of the volume (probably with `resize2fs /dev/sdb1`)

Comment: Thanks @Philippos! Isn't there a 6th step to be able to boot it? When I'll choose "HDD2" on the boot menu of my computer, it will look at /dev/sdb and won't find anything. Or would it automatically try to boot at /dev/sdb**1**? Is there something to do to configure the boot?